# Perl RegEx conversion to 'Basic'

Tags: regex, perl

I'm currently using grep in FreeBSD but it appears that FreeBSD does not support Perl RegEx. I'm wondering what the version for the following would be to have it work in FreeBSD using 'basic' expression:

```
grep -Po "(?<=addr.)[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"
```

Comment: Does your FreeBSD have perl installed?  Because that will support perl regex...

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `perl` - it is probably installed by default.

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if m/(?<=addr.)([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)/'
```

Of course at that point you probably don't need the look behind any more either.

```
perl -ne 'print join ("\n", m/addr.(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sed` but the below command won't work if more than one IP addresses exists.

```
$ echo '65 addr.567.67.879.89 foo bar' | sed -n "s/.*addr\.\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*/\1/p"
567.67.879.89
```